# `AssertionError` while installing `deepface` via pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, deepface

I'm trying to install `deepface` library via `pip` but it fails with `AssertionError`.

My system specs are:

- OS : POP-OS 22.04
- Python: Python-3.10.12
- Pip: pip-22.0.2

##### update 01

I did the following with `pip`:

```
pip install deepface
```

Here's the full error message that I got:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 165, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 389, in run
    to_install = resolver.get_installation_order(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 188, in get_installation_order
    weights = get_topological_weights(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 276, in get_topological_weights
    assert len(weights) == expected_node_count
AssertionError
```

##### update 02

I also tried to build from the source by following these, and it also resulted in the same error!
:

```
git clone https://github.com/serengil/deepface.git
cd deepface
pip install -e .
```

Links to the `deepface` library for your reference:

- https://pypi.org/project/deepface/
- https://github.com/serengil/deepface

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing an older version of `deepface` with no dependencies. also installed an older version of `dlib` beforehand. It seems the new release of `deepface` has some dependency issues with other libraries.
Here's my solution that worked on my system:

```
pip uninstall deepface -y
pip install dlib==19.24.0
pip install --no-deps deepface==0.0.79
```

My system specs are:

- OS Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64
- python 3.10.12
- pip 22.0.2
- NVIDIA-SMI Driver 545.29.06
- CUDA Version: 12.3
- GPU 1050
- Torch version 2.1.1+cu121

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I figured out that deepface does not yet work with tensorflow version 2.15.0. So to solve:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow    
pip install tensorflow==2.14.0
```

Then:

```
pip install deepface
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using the solution [A. Cloete suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77980085/238704), just a little different.

```
pip uninstall tensorflow

pip install dlib    
pip install tensorflow==2.14.0
pip install deepface
```

Good Look!

Answer (score -1):

[As explained](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/issues/929) in its github issue, you should upgrade pip as

```bash
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: this doesn't help. the GitHub issue you mentioned is the one I created and provided the solution there too, read the issue properly again.